# create chart with data from multiple sheets using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm simply trying to: create a chart with data from multiple sheets using VBA.

Something strange happens in my for loop where at the end every series has the same data applied.
(instead of every series showing data from the corresponding sheet, who are all different)

using this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineStacked
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="packetLoss"

For i = 1 To 8
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Next i

For i = 1 To 8
    Dim chartName As String
    chartName = "packetsOverTime" & (i + 3)
    Set xRng = Sheets(chartName).Range("B2:B1000")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = Sheets(chartName).Range("B2:B1000")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = chartName

Next i

End Sub
```

while this code correctly displays the data of "packetsOverTime5"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineStacked
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="packetLoss"

For i = 1 To 8
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Next i

'this is new: just apply data from "packetsOverTime5"
chartName = "packetsOverTime5"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = Sheets(chartName).Range("B2:B1000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = chartName

End Sub
```

And this last piece of code has the same result as the first piece:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineStacked
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="packetLoss"

For i = 1 To 8
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Next i

'this piece is back:
For i = 1 To 8
    Dim chartName As String
    chartName = "packetsOverTime" & (i + 3)
    Set xRng = Sheets(chartName).Range("B2:B1000")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = Sheets(chartName).Range("B2:B1000")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = chartName

Next i

'this piece doesn't have any effect now
chartName = "packetsOverTime5"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = Sheets(chartName).Range("B2:B1000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = chartName

End Sub
```

I have programming experience of over 4 years (never with VBA or/in excel tho), but I don't understand whats causing this problem.

If you have any clue please let me know :)

Thanks in advance, Jelle

Comment: do you mean "data form" or "data ***from***"? I can't quite tell if it's a typo or a language problem.

Comment: I meant from, just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (slightly different setup in my case)

```
Private Sub Tester()

Dim cht As Chart, s As Series, xRng As Range
Dim i As Long, chartName As String

    Set cht = Charts.Add
    cht.ChartType = xlLine
    cht.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="packetLoss"

    For i = 1 To 3

        chartName = "Sheet" & i
        Set xRng = Sheets(chartName).Range("A1:A10")

        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
            .Values = xRng
            .Name = chartName
        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah! I found the problem, xlLineStacked was a different type than I thought, thanks your example made me see that the data logic was correct and put me in the right direction.

Comment: Using xlLine as ChartType results in what I wanted.

Maybe you can change the ChartType to xlLine, then your answer will solve the problem I described so we can close this thread. 

Thanks for your time!